# I want to download an image from an API endpoint and store it in a struct variable iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using The Movie Database to search for movies.

1) I download the movies based on the search parameter

2) When Dequeueing the cell, I download the respective Poster

My issue is that I want to store the image in a struct's object so that I could re-use it in my app

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchResult", for: indexPath) as! SearchCell`

`var currentMedia = AppModel.searchList[indexPath.section]`

searchList holds data of type Media Model

```
if let posterPath = currentMedia.posterPath {
              TMDBClient.downloadPosterImage(path: posterPath) { data, error in
                  guard let data = data else {
                      return
                  }
                  let image = UIImage(data: data)
                cell.MediaPoster.image = image
                currentMedia.posterImage = image

              }
          }
```

My question is even after I do `currentMedia.posterImage = image` the UIImage is not stores in the struct.

Here is the struct of MediaModel

```
struct MediaModel {
    var posterImage: UIImage?
    let posterPath: String?
    let overview: String
    let releaseDate: String
    let Title: String
    let language: String
    let voteAverage: Double

    init(posterImage:UIImage,posterpath: String ,overview:String,release:String,title:String,language:String,vote:Double) {
        self.posterImage = posterImage
        self.posterPath = posterpath
        self.language = language
        self.overview = overview
        self.releaseDate = release
        self.Title = title
        self.voteAverage = vote

    }
}
```

Comment: debugged `currentMedia.posterImage = image` is called ? with the object called with

Comment: can you guide me on how I could do that

Comment: well, he meant you should set a breakpoint on  currentMedia.posterImage = image and check, whether the debugger ever stops there....

Comment: I found a fix and it's now in the answers if you're still curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently changing the struct to a class solved the issue of re-assignment.

As, I assume, it is common knowledge that structs pass by value  and classes pass by reference, so assigning a struct instance just assigns the **copy** of the object rather than the **reference**.

More about that here:

[Swift Classes vs Structs](https://learnappmaking.com/struct-vs-class-swift-how-to/)